# What's wrong with recursive Regex function code in python

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote a regex code which compares two strings. It recognises a special character '?' that allows zero or more instances of previous character. It works fine until there are two or more occasions of '?' in the string. And I can't make out why.

```
def single_character_string(a, b) -> "return True if characters match":
    """check if two characters match"""
    if len(a) == 0:
        return True
    elif len(b) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        if a == '.':
            return True
        else:
            if a == b:
                return True
            else:
                return False


def meta_question_result(temp):
    if len(temp) >= 2:
        if temp[1] == '?':
            k_1 = temp.replace(temp[0: 2], '')  # no char
            k_2 = temp.replace(temp[1], '')  # char
            return k_1, k_2


def check_pair_by_pair(template, check_string) -> "Strings are of Equal length! " \
                                                  "return True if lines are identical":
    """check if two strings match symbol by symbol. template may be less than string, the opposite
    is False"""
    if not template:  # exit from recursion
        return True
    if not check_string:  # exit from recursion
        return False
    if meta_question_result(template):
        t_1, t_2 = meta_question_result(template)
        if single_character_string(t_1[0], check_string[0]):
            return check_pair_by_pair(t_1[1:], check_string[1:])
        if single_character_string(t_2[0], check_string[0]):
            return check_pair_by_pair(t_2[1:], check_string[1:])
        else:
            return False
    elif single_character_string(template[0], check_string[0]):
        return check_pair_by_pair(template[1:], check_string[1:])
    else:
        return False

reg, st = input().split("|")
print(check_pair_by_pair(reg, st))
```

reg = "co?lou?r"
st = "colour"

gives True as expected,

reg = "co?lou?r"
st = "clor"

gives True as expected,

but...

reg = "co?lou?r"
st = "color"

gives False. I expected True.

Answer (score 0):

Found the bag.

Replace method replaces all instances of '?'. So the second '?' was replaced also and program didn't see it.
I should add an argument 'count' to replace method that is equal to 1.

k_1 = temp.replace(temp[0: 2], '', 1)  # no char

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).